# Java 8 Lambda specify map type and make it unmodifiable

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the following code, which produces months using lambdas.

```
 Map<Integer, String> tempMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

 EnumSet.allOf(Month.class).forEach(m -> {
        String formattedMonth = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM").format(m);
        tempMap.put(m.getValue(), formattedMonth);
    });

 MONTHS_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempMap);
```

I was wondering if this can be improved to perform all of these at one shot using lambdas?

```
return EnumSet.allOf(Month.class).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(
                        Month::getValue,
                        m -> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM").format(m)
                ), Collections::unmodifiableMap));
```

This doesn't work. Where do I specify that I would like to use a LinkedHashMap?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use [the `Collectors.toMap` overload that accepts a `Supplier<Map<K, V>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
Collectors.toMap(Month::getValue, 
  m -> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM").format(m)),
  (v1, v2) -> // whatever,
  LinkedHashMap::new)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What should I provide exactly for the merge function (the 3rd parameter)?

Comment: Whatever should happen when two keys collide, and if they shouldn't ever collide, you should just throw.

Comment: It works, but when I also specify that I want immutableMap, I get compilation error.

   EnumSet.allOf(Month.class).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(
                                Month::getValue,
                                m -> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM").format(m),
                                (v1, v2) -> null,
                                LinkedHashMap::new), Collections::unmodifiableMap
                ));

Comment: Not sure how to make it work with collectingAndThen method, but I wrapped your code above with Collections.unmodifiableMap method to get an unmodifiable map at the end.